# check if empty input add class to a div else remove class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a input with type `hidden` and two `divs`. 
How can I change the div to display based on value of input with type hidden?
i want to set display none to the div with class activeno if input does not value. and if input has value i want to set display none to div that called activeyes and show the div with classname activeno .
i wrote the below code for add and remove the class but it does not work .
here is my snippet :

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    tmpval = $('#inputi').val();
    if(tmpval == '') {
      $('.activeyes').addClass('activeyes2');
    } else {
      $('activeno').addClass('activeno2');
    }
});
```

```css
.mysite h1{ display:block;}
.activeyes{ display:none !important;}
.activeyes2{ display:block !important;}
.activeno{display:none !important;}
.activeno2{display:block !important;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" value="[##cms.query.enable##]" id="inputi"/>
<div class="mysite"> 
  <h1 class="activeyes"> Yes active </h1>
  <h1 class="activeno"> No not active </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: You have applied default display none to both the `<h1>` tags/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the class to change display but not removing the class already present. Note that use of `!important` is generally not advisable. You can just use `.show()` and `.hide()` to show or hide elements in jquery. while you show one hide the other one.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  tmpval = $('#inputi').val();
  if (tmpval == '') {
    $('.activeyes').show();
    $('.activeno').hide();
  } else {
    $('.activeno').show();
    $('.activeyes').hide();
  }
});
```

```css
.mysite h1 {
  display: block;
}

.activeyes {
  display: none;
}

.activeyes2 {
  display: block;
}

.activeno {
  display: none;
}

.activeno2 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="[##cms.query.enable##]" id="inputi" />
<div class="mysite">
  <h1 class="activeyes"> Yes active </h1>
  <h1 class="activeno"> No not active </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much !